# How to format text (i.e. double line breaks) in Play Store Release notes

Tags: html, xml, formatting, google-play

i noticed that the app release notes in the Google Play Store ("What's new") do not allow double line-breaks. Furthermore, all multiple spaces and line-breaks seem to be replaced by a single one. For example:

Version 1.0:
- new Icons
Version 1.1:
- bug fix

is formatted to:

Version 1.0:
-new Icons
Version 1.1:
- bug fix

This makes it impossible to make sections or header. Does anybody know formatting rules/tags here?

Stuff like

```
<br> <br /> <DIV></DIV>
```

does not work btw.

Comment: you can use html line and text formatting tags to try or use inline css padding and margin

Answer (score 0):

Use inline css in your tags

```
<strong style="padding:20px;">hello</strong>
```

you can use margin and padding to make gap space between 2 lines

Comment: Thanks but didn't work. The tag is displayed as it is.